# Search for Common Values between two different Databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, rds

I have two separate Databases (not tables) hosted on Amazon RDS, that I accessing through MySQL Workbench on Mac OSX El Capitan.

DB1 is structured like this:

```
--id --- first_name --- last_name --- city --- dob
```

DB2 is structured like this

```
--id --- company_name --- company_sector --- company_founder --- status
```

Is there a way for me to search for common values (db1.first_name + db1.last_name, db2.company_founder) between these two separate databases?

Also want to add that db1.id and db2.id aren't equal. They are from different sources.

Comment: First, what you are calling a database would appear to be a table.  Second, SQL offers many ways to do what you want . . . joins, `in`, and `exists` all come to mind.

Comment: No, I understand joins (inner, outer) and tables, but in this instance, they are two completely separate databases, compiled from different sources. I am only trying to see, for example, if someone in DB1 is a founder of a Company in DB2.

Comment: If the databases share a common engine, you should be able to use the `schema.table` notation to join between them. Otherwise, you'll have to use two local cursors and programmatically traverse them linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax would be something like:

```
select db1.person.*
from 
  db1.person
  inner join db2.person
    on db1.person.id = db2.person.id
    where ....
```

You can also assign names to shorten things as needed.